# Receive new value from edited cell in View-Based Table View

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

I have an View-Based Table View with some standard `NSTableCellView` data rows, which I fill from my data source. User can edit text field of a cell. Please, explain me, how to receive the new value, in order to I can update my data source, when user change text in cell?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to have a controller object with a xib file that contains your table view (the controller could be a subclass of NSViewController). Make this controller the delegate of your table view and put an IBAction connected to your text field in this class. You should also have an outlet to the table view.  Then, in your action method for the text filed, you can get the row that contains the text field from [tableView rowForView:sender]. Once you have the row, you can update the proper object in your array.